# Please explain the basic server setup code of Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, mern

In this code snippet:

```
Const express = require('express')

Const app = express();

 /*Typeof express = function
 Typeof app = function*/

 app.get()
```

My question is: if app is a function then how can we use a dot operator with it to call get function, and if we are creating a object of function express then why didn't we use new keyword to create an object.

Secondly, module.exports exports the literals in object format then why we are getting typeof express here a function.

If I am wrong anywhere, please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript [functions are objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), so this is valid:

```js
function x() { 
  console.log("this is x()");
}
x.y = function() { 
  console.log("this is x.y()");
}

x();
x.y();
```

Express and other JavaScript tools use this feature extensively.

If you're used to other languages where functions are just functions and not objects themselves this will seem extraordinarily strange.

Comment: oh! ya it was an extraordinary thing for me as it was not the case with cpp.still, can you please explain what's happening in the above code?

Comment: In pre-ES6 JavaScript this is how you actually made classes and objects. `function MyClass() { }` and then `MyClass.prototype.x = function() { ... }` to add instance methods. Thankfully `class` has made that mostly irrelevant, but this ability remains. `class Example { }` yields `typeof(Example)` to be...`'function'`.